# Is there a way to create text at 35 degree angle with CSS?

Tags: css

or control the rotation to specific degrees with CSS

Comment: Read up about CSS3 transforms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `transform: rotate(35deg)`. More in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/). For the moment, you have to add in the vendor-specific `transforms` as well, so for instance (cribbing from the article):

```
.rotate35 {
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);

    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);

    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(35deg);

    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(35deg);

    /* Standard */
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```

You can do a 35-degree angle for older IEs that require `filter`. This will work in IE7 and IE8:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.81915204, M12=-0.57357644, M21=0.57357644, M22=0.81915204,sizingMethod='auto expand');
```

Note, however, that the matrix transformation will leave you with a different offset than the CSS3 way shown above. You can compensate on the CSS3 side by setting the `-webkit-transform-origin` to `left top`, or on the IE side by positioning your element with a conditional style sheet or CSS hack.

Check out the [MS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the [cool page I used](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html) to generate the above.

Comment: You should also add the default css property "transform"

Comment: @DRP96: Thanks, overlapping edit and comment, I'd copied-and-pasted from the article (changing -90 to 35) and saved edits, then said "Hey, where's the standard one!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is but its CSS3, it of course presents problems when it comes to 'cross-browser' support.  But short answer, yes, in CSS3.

Example link: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/real-text-rotation-with-css

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
-webkit-transform:rotate(35deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(35deg);
transform:rotate(35deg);
```

for nearly all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-2d-transforms-20111215, more specifically the rotate(angle) function.

Note that this works only in CSS3.